# Yew - Trigger Event from another Component

Tags: rust, yew

I am currently trying to get to know the yew-library of rust (in combination with the component-framework "material-yew"). I've dug around the documentation a bit, but I cannot find an explanation for the given scenario: I would like to have two different components, where interacting with one (a Button) triggers an event for another (a Counter).

Currently I've only found examples where people have created a Component which contains both the button and the counter / the state of the counter - I would find it more useful tho to be able to separate those two pieces.

I would be grateful for any kind of doc-link or small code-snippet as to how I could implement this behavior (as I didn't find any).